# Similar to DataGrid.SelectedItem for ASP.Net GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, gridview, datagrid

I am looking whether there is a feature similar to DataGrid.SelectedItem for ASP.Net GridView.

The situation is, in WPF, on a button click, I am adding a class object using `DataGrid.Items.Add(class_object)`
In WPF DataGrid, if I click on a button in any datagrid row, I could use the following code to get the class object:

```
DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
MyClass editedrow = (MyClass)dg.SelectedItem;
```

My question is, is there any such feature in ASP.Net gridview to add a class object as well as to retrieve the class object on Button click ?

**Edit:**

I tried the following as said in the first comment:

```
GridView gv = sender as GridView;
MyClass editedrow = (MyClass)gv.SelectedRow;
```

It shows an error saying `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to 'Nubicus.gui.MyClass'`

**Edit 2**

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgSODetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                        onrowcommand="dgSODetails_RowCommand"  >
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNum" HeaderText="RowNum" ItemStyle-Width="0" Visible="false">
                                                <ItemStyle Width="0px" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_ItemType" HeaderText="Item Category" ItemStyle-Width="0"
                                                Visible="false">
                                                <ItemStyle Width="0px" />
                                            </asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Item_Name" HeaderText="Item Name"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Item_Quantity" HeaderText="Qty."></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Unit_Name" HeaderText="Unist"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Line_Discount_Percentage" HeaderText="Disc. %"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Line_Discount_Amount" HeaderText="Disc. Amt."></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SO_Item_Final_Price" HeaderText="Total Amt."></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnCommand="dgSODetails_Command"
                                                        CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnCommand="dgSODetails_Command"
                                                        CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You can use `GridView.SelectedRow`.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting an error, which I have added as an edit in the question

Comment: You will get `GridViewRow` not your custom class.

Comment: No you don't add a class object to GridView instead assign class array or list to GridView DataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
GridView gv = sender as GridView;
GridViewRow editedrow = (GridViewRow)gv.SelectedRow;


    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnCommand="dgSODetails_Command"
CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"
OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />


protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);
        string SO_ItemType= row.Cells[1].Text 



}
```

Comment: Can I cast this to the class object?

Comment: gv.SelectedRow returns null.

Comment: please post .aspx for of GridVIew

Comment: @Nubicus you can get values as i did for `ItemType`